# 5 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError (Cannot Find)

Tags: plugins, functions, fatal-error

I recently migrated a WordPress site over from PHP5 to PHP7. One of our custom file listing functions (outputs a listing of files from a folder on a server directory) is failing on the new server on PHP7. I know there is an argument conflict but I cannot figure out how to rectify it.

**The error:**

5 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function printDirectory(), 3 passed in /nas/content/live/lfccedu/wp-content/plugins/lfcc/lfcc.php on line 1026 and exactly 4 expected in /nas/content/live/lfccedu/wp-content/plugins/lfcc/lfcc.php:1014\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/lfccedu/wp-content/plugins/lfcc/lfcc.php(1026): printDirectory('https://lfccedu...', '/nas/content/li...', 'files/documents...')\n#1 /nas/content/live/lfccedu/wp-content/plugins/lfcc/lfcc.php(973): printDirectory('https://lfccedu...', '/nas/content/li...', 'files/documents...', 'ASC')\n#2 [internal function]: DirectoryList(Array, '', 'lfcc_directory_...')\n#3 /nas/content/live/lfccedu/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(325): call_user_func('DirectoryList', Array, '', 'lfcc_directory_...')\n#4 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)\n#5 /nas/content/live/lfccedu/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(199): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(captio...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[caption id="at...')\n#6 [internal function]: do_shortcode('[caption id="at... in /nas/content/live/lfccedu/wp-content/plugins/lfcc/lfcc.php on line 1014

**Here's the code:**

```
function DirectoryList($atts)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'file_root' => '',
        'folder' => '',
        'sort' => 'ASC'
    ), $atts ));

    $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    return printDirectory($protocol . $domain, $file_root, $folder, $sort);
}

add_shortcode('lfcc_directory_list', 'DirectoryList');

function ScheduleUpdateTime()
{
    $aSettings = get_option('lfcc_external_db_settings');
    $sDateTime = (time() < strtotime(date("Y-m-d ".$aSettings['cache_time'],time()))) ? date("Y-m-d",(time()-(60*60*24))) : date("Y-m-d",time());
    $sDateTime .= ' ' . $aSettings['cache_time'];
    return date('M j, Y, \a\t g:i a', strtotime($sDateTime));
}

add_shortcode('lfcc_last_schedule_update', 'ScheduleUpdateTime');

function getFileList($root, $sort)
{
    $files = array();
    if (is_dir($root))
    {
        if ($handle = opendir($root)) 
        {
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
            {
                if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                    $files[] = $entry;
                }
            }
        }
        natsort($files);
        if ($sort == 'DESC')
        {
            $files = array_reverse($files);
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

/**
 * Outputs a list of directories and files recursively.
 */
function printDirectory($url, $root, $path, $sort) 
{
    $sRtn = '';
    $current_dir = $root . '/' . $path;
    $files = getFileList($current_dir, $sort);
    foreach ($files as $f) 
    {
        $file_path = $current_dir . '/' . $f;
        if (is_dir($file_path)) 
        {
            // If it is a directory, output the directory name and look inside it for more
            $sRtn .= "<strong>" . $f . "</strong><ul>";
            $sRtn .= printDirectory($url, $root, $path . '/' . $f);
            $sRtn .= "</ul></li>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            // If it is a file, output a link to the file.
            $info = pathinfo($f);
            $sRtn .= '<li><a class="icon ' . $info['extension'] . '" href="' . $url . '/' . $path . '/' . $f . '" target="_blank">' . $info['filename'] . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    return $sRtn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it appears that your prior iteration made use of the looser nature of PHP5:

> Too few arguments to function printDirectory(), 3 passed ... and
>   exactly 4 expected in ...

I see that you define printDirectory() with four parameters:

- $url
- $root
- $path
- $sort

The first time you call this function, you pass all four parameters.  Unfortunately, when you call it recursively (within the function itself) you only pass three of the four.

```
$sRtn .= printDirectory($url, $root, $path . '/' . $f);
```

Try passing the $sort variable in that recursive call.

Comment: Oh man can't believe I missed that. Thank you!!!!!!